# REACTJS axios post Messsage Sent(204 no Content)

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer

el formulario envia y llega a el correo. solo que llega vacío como un dato undefined y por supuesto las etiquetas que están en `<h1></h1> y <p></p>` eso si llega completo. no se que error pueda estar cometiendo aqui. **en el inspector cuando reviso en network para ver las cabeceras y su estatus salen 2 uno contiene el mensaje enviado con estatus 200 y el otro dice 204 no content**. y por supuesto en cuanto al el formulario lleva correctamente sus etiqueta name='nome' xxx. xxx. xxx

CLIENTE

```
const [Datos, setDatos] = useState({
        nome: '',
        asunto: '',
        email:   '',
        message: ''
    })
    const HandleInputChange = (e) => {
        setDatos({
            ...Datos,
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }
function submitEmail(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/send",{  
          data: setDatos(Datos),
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
          }
        }).then((response)=>{
          if (response.data.status === 'success'){
              console.log("Message Sent."); 
          }else if(response.data.status === 'fail'){
              console.log("Message failed to send.")
          }
        })
    }
```

servidor Nodejs

```
app.post('/send', (req, res, next) => {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp-gmail.com",
        port: 465,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL,
          pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
      });
    var mail = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL,
      to: process.env.RECIVER,
      subject: 'Portafolio fotografias',
      html: `<h1>Details</h1>
             <p>CLIENTE:${req.body.nome}</p>
             <p>CONTACTO:${req.body.email}</p>
             <p>Asunto:${req.body.asunto}</p>
             <p>MENSAJE DEL CLIENTE:${req.body.message}</p>
          `      
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: 'fail'
        })
      } else {
        res.json({
         status: 'success'
        })
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/send", { data: setDatos(Datos)
```

-------->

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/send", Datos, headers: {...})
```

Estas enviando el resultado del setState, el cual es undefined, en el backend al parsear la informacion no hay ningun valor. Todo es undefined, por cierto... Tienes que validar tus datos en el backend, esto es inseguro (Lo comento porque capaz lo borraste, no lo se).

Comment: Si envias { data: Datos } entonces en el servidor, tienes que colocar req.body.data.nome

Comment: el header lo dejo tal cual como esta?

Comment: Creo que no hace falta que le pongas headers adicionales si usas body-parser. Por defecto tiene el valor que colocaste.